# Checkboxes in a wordpress form are not showing as checked when selected

Tags: forms

https://farmdogz.com.au/

https://farmdogz.com.au/adoptions/

i'm not sure what any of this means
i just need help please

Comment: Where do the checkboxes come from? Are they your code or from a plugin. If it’s your code you’re going to need to share it if you expect any help. If it’s not your code you need to ask its author for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using the WPForms plugin. The checkbox is getting checked, but the styling of the check mark sets its color to white on a white background, so you are unable to see the checkbox as checked/selected. Check to see what CSS styling options there are with WPForms or try to override the styling in a custom style sheet. Otherwise, you will need to follow up with WPForms support since 3rd party plugin support is off topic here.